# How to integrate a custom tensorflow lite client in android

Tags: android, android-ndk, bazel, object-detection-api, tensorflow-lite

I am trying to reproduce the work defined in [tensorflow/models/research](https://github.com/richardbrks/models/tree/lstm_object_detection_improvements/research/lstm_object_detection) to build a custom object detection model to run in android. I am able to get all the way to build a `detect.tflite` FlatBuffer file; however, I am not able to understand how to integrate the custom tflite cpp library into something that is useable by android.

In the [tflite directory](https://github.com/richardbrks/models/tree/lstm_object_detection_improvements/research/lstm_object_detection/tflite), I ran the following bazel command:

```sh
bazel build //:mobile_lstd_tflite_client
```

producing the following output (other files are created, but bazel specifies these as being the target):

```
bazel-bin/libmobile_lstd_tflite_client.lo
bazel-bin/libmobile_lstd_tflite_client.so
```

To test this model, I am working on creating a demo app similar to [TensorFlow's example object detection android app](https://github.com/tensorflow/examples/tree/master/lite/examples/object_detection/android), but replacing the object detection with my custom detection model. But [their model](https://github.com/tensorflow/examples/blob/master/lite/examples/object_detection/android/app/src/main/java/org/tensorflow/lite/examples/detection/tflite/TFLiteObjectDetectionAPIModel.java) appears to be defined in java, and just uses the tflite library to call `org.tensorflow.lite.Interpreter`.

**My question is**: how do I use the built `libmobile_lstd_tflite_client.lo` and `libmobile_lstd_tflite_client.so` in an android project?

I see 2 potential paths:

**1. Use CMake and NDK and add the .so file directly to the android project**

Reference sources:

- [Android Studio: Add C and C++ code to Your project](https://developer.android.com/studio/projects/add-native-code.html)
- [android-ndk Example](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-ndk/tree/master/hello-libs)

This seems like the correct way to me. It looks like would only use the .so file, so I'm still uncertain how (or if) the .lo file is used.

**2. Use bazel to build an Android library (.aar file)**

This would involve adding build definitions similar to what is in [tesorflow/lite/java/BUILD](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/lite/java/BUILD)  to get from a `cc_library` to a `java_library` to an `android_library` to an `aar_with_jni`.

For this path, I am uncertain where the to specify `libmobile_lstd_tflite_client.so` (or the .lo file) as a dependency.

Any insight into how to proceed forward would be greatly appreciated!

**EDIT (2019-08-08)**

Tensorflow's [smartreply demo](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/tree/master/tensorflow/lite/models/smartreply) looks similar to what I'm trying to accomplish, which leans to me thinking that path #2 (using bazel to build all the way up to an apk) is the correct option. I will just need to write a jni to help bridge the C++ to java.